# Can't change button text inside setTimeout function

Tags: vue.js

I have got follow Vue-js App:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/1.0.26/vue.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            .mydiv
            {
                border: 1px black dashed;
                font-size: 2em;
            }
        </style>

    <script>
    var App = null; // it's global because function behind will overwrite it's with Vue App instance
    window.onload = function() 
    {
        new Vue(
        {
              el: '#app',
              data: 
              {
                btntext: "OK"
              },
              methods:
              {
                change: function()
                {
                    this.btntext = "cancel";
                    setTimeout(function() {console.log("test"); this.btntext = "text changed";},1000);
                }
              }

        })  
    }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <div class="mydiv">
                <button v-on:click="change">{{btntext}}</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

After running I am getting "test" on console, but button do not change it's text to `text changed`. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function given to setTimeout does not have the same "this" as your Vue. You could use the bind function:

```js
new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 data: {
  btntext: "OK"
 },
 methods: {
  change: function () {
   this.btntext = "cancel";
   setTimeout(function () {
    console.log("test");
    this.btntext = "text changed";
   }.bind(this), 1000);
  }
 }
})
```

```css
.mydiv{
  border: 1px black dashed;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/1.0.26/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="mydiv">
    <button v-on:click="change">{{btntext}}</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.bind(this)` will bind this top level function?

Comment: Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind for an explanatino on bind.

Basically you can do:
var o = {foo:'bar'};
setTimeout(function(){console.log(this.foo);}.bind(o), 100);

Comment: @user1432751 first argument of `Function.bind` is `thisArg`, and will change what object `this` points to. So in the case of this example, it will change `this` from pointing to global `this` (== `window`) to `this` inside Vue, where your `btntext` is stored.

Comment: How do you do it with ecmascript?

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand the context of `this` keyword. When in setTimeout callback function, `this` refers to different object that `this` before it. To solve this issue, you should solve reference to this before the callback or if you're going to use ES2015, you can change `function () {...}` with arrow function `() => {...}`, which will automatically save reference to outer `this` and use it instead of actual `this` inside the function. But if you're going to use that, make sure it's supported across all your target browsers, or alternatively use a compiler to ES5, most popular of which is [Babel](http://babeljs.io/).

Comment: Something like this?

`
      change: () =>
    {
     this.btntext = "cancel";
     setTimeout(function() {console.log("test"); this.btntext = "text changed";},1000);
    }

` ?

Comment: No, use arrow function as the function passed to setTimeout, like `setTimeout(() => { ... }, 1000)`